# Quartz.Net How to use XML to configure several jobs

Tags: c#, xml, quartz.net

This is my XML file, it's not working at all.I want to configure multiple jobs using XML file, i searched for  this and got no answer, so could anyone help me about this?

```
  <schedule>

    <job>
      <name>employee</name>
      <group>SampleGroup</group>
      <description>My job</description>
      <job-type>Quartz.Server.Interface_manip, Quartz.Server</job-type>
      <durable>true</durable>
      <recover>false</recover>
    </job>
    <trigger>
      <cron>
        <name>employeeTrigger</name>
        <group>SampleGroup</group>
    <description>Simple trigger to simply fire sample job</description>
    <job-name>employee</job-name>
    <job-group>SampleGroup</job-group>
    <misfire-instruction>SmartPolicy</misfire-instruction>
    <cron-expression>0 13 10 * * ?</cron-expression>
    </cron>
 </trigger>
    <job>
      <name>SampleJob</name>
      <group>SampleGroup</group>
      <description>My job</description>
      <job-type>Quartz.Server.Next_Year_Quota, Quartz.Server</job-type>
      <durable>true</durable>
      <recover>false</recover>
    </job>
    <trigger>
      <cron>
        <name>SampleTrigger</name>
        <group>SampleGroup</group>
        <description>Simple trigger to simply fire sample job</description>
        <job-name>SampleJob</job-name>
        <job-group>SamplerGroup</job-group>
        <misfire-instruction>SmartPolicy</misfire-instruction>
        <cron-expression>0 31 10 * * ?</cron-expression>
      </cron>
    </trigger>
  </schedule>
</job-scheduling-data>
```

it executed perfectly if there's only the first job, and it did nothing when i added the second one, but i really need it to execute multiple jobs, and it will be convenient to use XML.Thank you very much.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21486847/context-trigger-jobdatamap-values-via-xml-configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see your issue is due to the fact that you are grouping your job and trigger together. Try grouping your jobs together, and your triggers together. 
Also, I don't know  if you intended to exclude your xml and job-scheduling-data tags, but you need those.

As an extra, I find this tool helpful. 
[Cron Expression Generator & Explainer - Quartz](https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html)

**Try this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<job-scheduling-data xmlns="http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/JobSchedulingData">
  <schedule>
    <job>
    <name>employee</name>
    <group>SampleGroup</group>
    <description>My job</description>
    <job-type>Quartz.Server.Interface_manip, Quartz.Server</job-type>
    <durable>true</durable>
    <recover>false</recover>
    </job>
    <job>
    <name>SampleJob</name>
    <group>SampleGroup</group>
    <description>My job</description>
    <job-type>Quartz.Server.Next_Year_Quota, Quartz.Server</job-type>
    <durable>true</durable>
    <recover>false</recover>
    </job>
    <trigger>
    <cron>
        <name>employeeTrigger</name>
        <group>SampleGroup</group>
        <description>Simple trigger to simply fire sample job</description>
        <job-name>employee</job-name>
        <job-group>SampleGroup</job-group>
        <misfire-instruction>SmartPolicy</misfire-instruction>
        <cron-expression>0 13 10 * * ?</cron-expression>
    </cron>
    </trigger>
    <trigger>
    <cron>
        <name>SampleTrigger</name>
        <group>SampleGroup</group>
        <description>Simple trigger to simply fire sample job</description>
        <job-name>SampleJob</job-name>
        <job-group>SamplerGroup</job-group>
        <misfire-instruction>SmartPolicy</misfire-instruction>
        <cron-expression>0 31 10 * * ?</cron-expression>
    </cron>
    </trigger>
  </schedule>
</job-scheduling-data>
```